# How can we type Arabic in textboxes using mvc3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project i need to enter data to textboxes in arabic.shall it is possible to enter the data  in arabic by using culture settings.?

Comment: Are you asking how to get arabic into the text boxes? Or just process it on the back end?

Comment: asking for how to type it in textboxes..not in back end

Comment: <input type="text" lang="ar" xml:lang="ar" maxlength="75" id="Arabic" />..But its not working

Comment: You want the user to be "forced" to type in Arabic in those textboxes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i enter Arabic in TextBox using Mvc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987331/how-can-i-enter-arabic-in-textbox-using-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have Arabic language install on your computer.

Control Panel > Region and Language >

[image]

Then you can select whatever language you want to type from language toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution I can think of:

1. Go to [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/).
2. Set to Translate from English to Arabic
3. Type your phrase
4. Copy and Paste

Example: http://translate.google.com/#auto/ar/I%20like%20coffee